# Generating Accessible PDFs in Python

Tags: python, pdf, accessibility

I am attempting to generate automated reports which are Accessible (508 Compliant). I read that `reportlab` is capable of generating pdf which are accessible. I have yet to see any examples of this being true. However, there is a paid option. I have been experimenting extensively with various packages including pikepdf and pymupdf. While the functionality of making documents accessible does not appear to be particularly complex it does appear to be not something that has yet been implemented on an open source software suite.

As I have blind friends it is disappointing to see this basic feature missing. The basic requirements are:

1. tagged title
2. tagged table headers and rows
3. figures and tables having alternative text (mostly explaining what the content is)
4. having a specified tab order

The following is some example code to generate a simple pdf in reportlab. Could someone tell me how to change my code allow the generated content to be accessible? If not, could you point me to an option which would produce an accessible pdf document?

My only solution for automated reports right now is generate them as html, open in MS Word, export as Pdf.

```py
import pandas as pd
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter, landscape
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph, Spacer, Table, TableStyle
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_CENTER

# Metadata for PDF
pdf_title = "Sample Report"
pdf_author = "Your Name"
pdf_subject = "Sample PDF Report"
pdf_keywords = "report, sample, pdf, python"

# Sample data for the table
data = {
    'Item Name': ['Item A', 'Item B', 'Item C', 'Item D'],
    'Quantity': [10, 14, 34, 22],
    'Price': [25, 56, 80, 120],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create the PDF document
doc = SimpleDocTemplate("sample_report.pdf", pagesize=landscape(letter),
                        title=pdf_title, author=pdf_author, subject=pdf_subject,
                        keywords=pdf_keywords)

# Set up the page styles and content
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name="Centered", alignment=TA_CENTER))

title = Paragraph("Sample Report", styles['Heading1'])
author = Paragraph("Author: Your Name", styles['Heading2'])
subject = Paragraph("Subject: Sample PDF Report", styles['Heading2'])

doc.build([title, Spacer(1, 0.5), author, Spacer(1, 0.25), subject])

table_data = [['Item Name', 'Quantity', 'Price']]
table_data += df.values.tolist()

table = Table(table_data)
table.setStyle(TableStyle([
    ('BACKGROUND', (0, 0), (-1, 0), colors.grey),
    ('TEXTCOLOR', (0, 0), (-1, 0), colors.whitesmoke),
    ('ALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'CENTER'),
    ('FONTNAME', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 'Helvetica-Bold'),
    ('FONTSIZE', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 14),
    ('BOTTOMPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 12),
    ('BACKGROUND', (0, 1), (-1, -1), colors.beige),
    ('GRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 1, colors.black),
    ('BOX', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 2, colors.black)
]))

doc.build([title, Spacer(1, 0.5), author, Spacer(1, 0.5), subject, Spacer(1, 0.5), table])
```

Comment: There is a long-standing mailing list for ReportLab users at https://pairlist2.pair.net/mailman/listinfo/reportlab-users .  The authors monitor it quite closely.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks but reportlab is pretty explicit that the only option to achieve accessibility is through their paid product. I can't afford their rates.

Answer (score 0):

No answer sorry, but have been looking for something similar.

For those reading this post that aren't familiar with PDF accessibility, PDFs require several things to be used by assistive technologies, most importantly a functional tag tree. This tree can be found by opening Adobe Pro (paid version only) and going to View > Show/Hide > Navigation Panes > Accessibility Tags. Tags are similar to HTML and identify content as headings, text, images etc. It is a system unique to PDFs.

It is a legal requirement in many countries for PDFs to be accessible, but so far I have not seen any free solution to generating accessible tagged PDFs from HTML. There are paid programs that can do this but it's not feasible for a lot of companies or operations.

A lot of HTML pairs super easily with tags e.g. heading levels. An open source library like wkhtmltoPDF would be perfect for adding this functionality to, for someone who had the understanding and ability. [Unfortunately it's not on the dev team's radar right now.](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1616)

If anyone coming across this knows of a free solution, please share. There are many people who need this.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Playwright](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro), in python to generate tagged PDFs.  Playwright gives you access to a headless browser and I use Playwright in combination with [Chromium](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ku6QNtAHEqVnRGqFzpmlMe1fowkjCX9miHj8Kx1cFlk/edit#heading=h.7nki9mck5t64), which is capable of exporting an HTML page to PDF with tags.  The structural tags used in the HTML are preserved in the exported PDF.

The basic outline of the process is to assemble your publication as HTML. Save that to a file, use Playwright to open the file in Chromium, and then instruct Chromium to export the file to PDF.

```
import os
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

# Make an HTML file
html = """
<html>
   <head><title>Tagged PDF</title></head>
   <body>
       <h1>Tagged PDF</h1>
       <table>
           <thead><tr><th>A table col</th></tr></thead>
           <tbody><tr><td>A table cell</td></tr></tbody>
       </table>
       <p>A paragraph</p>
       <ul><li>A list</li></ul>
   </body>
</html>"""
file_key = 'publication.html'
with open(f'{os.getcwd()}/{file_key}', "w") as wh:
    wh.write(html)
    wh.close()
# Instruct playwright to open the file in chromium
with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(
        headless=True,
    )
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto(f'file://{os.getcwd()}/{file_key}')
    # Export the file to PDF
    page.pdf(
        path=f'{os.getcwd()}/tagged.pdf',
        format="Letter",
        margin={'top':'20px', 'bottom':'40px'},
        print_background=True,
        display_header_footer=True,
        footer_template=footer()
    )

def footer():
    html = """
    <html>
      <body>
        <p>the footer</p>
      </body>
    </html>
    """
    return html
```

The tagged.pdf in PDF Studio showing the resulting tags:
[image: Viewing the tagged.pdf structure in PDF Studio]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying is the barrier is to S. 508 compliance here.  The Section 508 [guidance on PDFs says](https://www.section508.gov/create/pdfs/) "ensure the resulting PDF file is properly tagged to support accessibility".  For examples, it links to the [WCAG guidance](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/pdf) on PDF tagging and many of the provided examples display tag trees that look just like this example.  Do you have an example of where the Chromium-generated tags fail to meet 508/WCAG guidance?

Comment: Your issues then seem to be with the WCAG guidance and/or the verification tools that pass sub-standard files.  I was hoping for an example of where the tagging output by this process failed to provide what the WCAG spec suggests. What you seem to be implying are situations where the tagging fails the needs of the user.  Or the assistive technology operating on the tags fails the user perhaps.  What would help the readers of this question, who have come here with a desire to publish accessible PDFs, would be examples of PDF tags that users need that the process doesn't provide.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can try `wkhtmltopdf`, he can convert html to pdf, and the effect is also very good. In fact, writing html is much easier than writing pdf. This is its official website: [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/)
.There is also a python package `pdfkit` that encapsulates it, github:[pdfkit](https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit)

Comment: I tested wkhtmltopdf, thank you and the pdfs generated do not pass the pdf accessibility check any more than any of the other tools.

Comment: what accessibility check? Can you elaborate? I am very interested.

Comment: Acrobat Pro > tools > Accessibility > Accessibility Check